# libgdx write text on texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I know I'm a bit ahead of libgdx because it's actually more a 2D-library but I'm working on a 3D app powered by libgdx and need to write text on a model.

I already come so far that I'm able to change texture of my model dynamically. **Now I need to write text to a texture to apply this texture to my model... Is this already possible with libgdx? If yes, how?**
Till now I only found tutorials how to write text on screen wit BitmapFont but only via SpriteBatch and I don't think there would be a possibility to write the output of spritebatch on a texture...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can send the output of a `SpriteBatch` (or any OpenGL drawing command) to a texture instead of sending it to the screen.  In Libgdx you use a [`FrameBuffer` object](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html) to accomplish this.  This tutorial covers the basics and a bit more: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/FrameBufferObjects

Comment: I think this works... Actually my complete model turns black... Is there a way to check what the texture with written text looks like? Because I read something about problems with the size of text... Maybe it's just written to big...

Comment: Ok, there has to be another problem. For testing purposes I set the color of BitmapFont after new BitmapFont() to red and the color of spritebatch to blue before batch.begin() but the model stays black. If the texture would contain the font shouldn't the model become red?

Comment: It's also not possible to get the Pixmap and write the bytes into a file... I always get "Pixmap already disposed"-Error regardless if I'm trying to get it before or after FrameBuffer or SpriteBatch .end()

Answer (score 0):

With Normal bitmap fonts you get a `pixmap` of ALL the `Glpths`, and can do bitmap copies.

```
pixmap.drawPixmap(fontPixmap, x_place, (TILE_HEIGHT - aGlyph.height) / 2,
aGlyph.srcX, aGlyph.srcY, aGlyph.width, aGlyph.height);

The only way (I have found) of drawing raster fonts (`.ttf`) is as follows:

    Example framework:
    ==================
    package com.badlogic.gdx.tests.bullet;

    /**
    Question       :   libgdx write text on texture
    interpreted as :   In libgdx, how to create dynamic texture?
    Answer         :   Use a private render function to draw in a private frame buffer and convert the frame buffer to Pixmap, create Texture.
    Author  :   Jon Goodwin
    **/

    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
    ...//(ctrl-shift-o) to auto-load imports in Eclipse


    public class BaseBulletTest extends BulletTest
    {
    //class variables
    =================
    public Texture           texture     = null;//create this
    public Array<Disposable> disposables = new Array<Disposable>();
    public Pixmap            pm          = null;
    //---------------------------
        @Override
        public void create ()
        {
            init();
        }
    //---------------------------
        public static void init ()
        {
            if(texture == null) texture(Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE);
            TextureAttribute ta_tex     = TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture);
            final Material material_box = new Material(ta_tex, ColorAttribute.createSpecular(1, 1, 1, 1),
                                                       FloatAttribute.createShininess(8f));
            final long attributes1      = Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates;
            final Model boxModel = modelBuilder.createBox(1f, 1f, 1f, material_box, attributes1);
            ...
        }
    //---------------------------
        public Texture texture(Color fg_color, Color bg_color)
        {
            Pixmap pm = render( fg_color, bg_color );
            texture = new Texture(pm);//***here's your new dynamic texture***
            disposables.add(texture);//store the texture
        }
    //---------------------------
        public Pixmap render(Color fg_color, Color bg_color)
        {
            int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

            SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

            m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, (int)(width * m_fboScaler), (int)(height * m_fboScaler), false);
            m_fbo.begin();
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(bg_color.r, bg_color.g, bg_color.b, bg_color.a);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            Matrix4 normalProjection = new Matrix4().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),  Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(normalProjection);

            spriteBatch.begin();
            spriteBatch.setColor(fg_color);
            //do some drawing ***here's where you draw your dynamic texture***
            font.draw(spriteBatch, "5\n6\n2016",  width/4, height - 20);//multi-line draw
            ...
            spriteBatch.end();//finish write to buffer

            pm = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);//write frame buffer to Pixmap

            m_fbo.end();
    //      pm.dispose();
    //      flipped.dispose();
    //      tx.dispose();
            m_fbo.dispose();
            m_fbo = null;
            spriteBatch.dispose();
    //      return texture;
            return pm;
        }
    //---------------------------
    }//class BaseBulletTest
    //---------------------------
```